# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given new one

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am develop a simple authentication application in django but I get this error:
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

**my view**

```
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View

from .forms import RegisterForm


def home(request):
   return render(request, 'users/home.html')


class RegisterView(View):
   form_class = RegisterForm
   initial = {'key': 'value'}
   template_name = 'users/register.html'

   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(to='/')

      return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = self.form_class(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

           username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
           messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')

           return redirect(to='/')

       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
   form_class = LoginForm

   def form_valid(self, form):
       remember_me = form.cleaned_data.get('remember_me')

       if not remember_me:
           self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

           self.request.session.modified = True

       return super(CustomLoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**application urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', home, name='users-home'),
path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='users-register'),  # This is what we added
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True, template_name='users/login.html',
                                       authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

**my form**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                             required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name',
                                                           'class': 'form-control',
                                                           }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name',
                                                          'class': 'form-control',
                                                          }))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           required=True,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                         'class': 'form-control',
                                                         }))
email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email',
                                                       'class': 'form-control',
                                                       }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                              'class': 'form-control',
                                                              'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                              'id': 'password',
                                                              }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm 
Password',
                                                              'class': 'form-control',
                                                              'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                              'id': 'password',
                                                              }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           required=True,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                         'class': 'form-control',
                                                         }))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                           required=True,
                           widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                             'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                             'id': 'password',
                                                             'name': 'password',
                                                             }))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'remember_me']
```

**and the last one my setting add these**

1. add the application name to the installed app
2. SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
3. LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
4. LOGIN_URL = 'login'

Comment: could you post the full stack trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution just uninstall Pillow library with
pip uninstall Pillow
and uninstall django library and reinstall them
it worked for me...

Comment: This answer is not related to the question

Comment: I did what i told here and it worked for me